# Get value from dropdown in a table row codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm having problem getting value from dropdownlist that generated using foreach $data as $d according to database
the code is like this

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            foreach ($data as $d) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $d->id; ?></td>
            <td>
                <select name="option" id="option">
                    <option value="A" selected>A</option>
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

how can i get the dropdown value according the data that showing on the table?

like if there's 3 data showing (that means 3 dropdown with same name and id) and i get 3 values for each data?

Edit: in short, the data that i need to sent to my controller is:
- the value from selected dropdownlist
- the id values from each row so i can using it for my query later combining with value from dropdownlist

Note: i tried using this in foreach

```
$x=1;


$x++;
```

with

```
name/id="option<?php echo $x;?>"
```

and this for each table row

```
<input type="hidden" id="id<?php echo $x; ?>" name="id<?php echo $x; ?>" value="<?php echo $d->id; ?>">
```

it works, but i think there's still better way for this

Comment: Could you elaborate the question a little? I'm unsure if you are asking how to fill the options with the correct data or how to get the value of the selected option.

Comment: @da39a3ee i edited it, maybe it can help a little, sorry for my bad english

Comment: I've edited my answer. Is that what you mean? There are probably more complex, "cleaner" answers that use libraries but in basic PHP that should be it. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, below is the proper implementation of a select element with a foreach loop creating the list items.

```
<select name="foo">
    <option value="0">-------</option>
    <?php 
        foreach($foo as $row)
            echo '<option value="'.$row->DataID.'">'.$row->Data.'</option>';
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you for the respond, but i using foreach loop no for the dropdown list element, but for the table rows, and the each row contain dropdown that generated alongside the data in database

maybe my explanation is not good, sorry

Comment: @Teletubbies it sounds like you need a doubly nested foreach loop. One for the table rows and the other for the select element. I can't know for sure unless I see the SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

So assuming your data is structured in an array e.g.

```
$data = [
    "A" => [
        "id" => 1,
        "values" => [
            "lorem",
            "ipsum",
            "donec"
        ]
    ],
    "B" => [
        "id" => 2,
        "value" => [
            "lorem",
            "ipsum",
            "donec"
        ]
    ],
    "C" => [
        "id" => 3,
        "value" => [
            "lorem",
            "ipsum",
            "donec"
        ]
    ],
];
```

Printing the array as dropdowns would be done like this

```
<form method="post" action="/url/to/post/form/to">
...
    <?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
        <select name="options[<?php $row['id']; ?>]" id="option">
            <?php foreach ($row['values'] as $value): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
...
</form>
```

This will result in a dropdown with three options; A, B and C.
If the user select one of these options and the form is POSTed You can read the selected option as:

```
...
    foreach ($_POST['options'] as $option) {
        var_dump($option);
    }
...
```

Note: Make sure to do proper validation on the field and it's values to prevent unwanted, undesired behaviour in your application.

Reference material:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp
http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/2.html

Comment: thank you for the respond, but i using foreach loop no for the dropdown list element, but for the table rows, and the each row contain dropdown that generated alongside the data in database

maybe my explanation is not good, sorry

Comment: So each row contains a dropdown and you want to get the value of that nested dropdown?